# como fazer uma query ordenando uma coluna crescente e outra descendente

Tags: mysql, sql

preciso fazer uma query que busca uma coluna crescente e na mesma query outra coluna em descendente por exemplo no resultado abaixo:

```
item   | quantidade
carro  |    400
carro  |    340
dado   |    240
disco  |    180
disco  |    120
faca   |    89
faca   |    59
```

gostaria que saísse assim o resultado
segue minha query abaixo:

```
SELECT * FROM qe.etiquetas_recortadas_aoi ignore index(PRIMARY) 
where line = 'AOI-1' 
and brand = 'NBK'  
and material_name_crop <> 'Borrada_1'  
order by qty_pass desc, material_name asc;
```

Comment: qual seu erro? acredito que dessa forma o `order by` funcione.

Comment: a sintaxe está correta. O seu exemplo de resultado não bate com o select (item, quantidade não aparecem na query), mas acredito que seja material_name e qty_pass. Se for isso, só mudar o `order by` para `order by material_name asc, qty_pass desc`, mas não deu pra entender o seu problema....

Comment: @RicardoPontual Também achei que fosse isso, tanto que respondi e nem tinha visto seu comentário ! rs ... fui pelo `qty_pass` ser o `int` e `material_name` o `string` do exemplo que ele deu, mas o problema é que o exemplo está ordenado pelos 2, e é aí que ele deve ter se confundido no dele.

Comment: Parece ser isso mesmo, só uma questão de inverter os campos, engraçado é ele ter chegado até o `order by` e não tentar mudar a ordem dos campos :)

Comment: Só corrigindo, `String` não, `varchar` né ! rs

Answer (score 2):

**Da forma que está ordenando:**

```
ORDER BY qty_pass DESC, material_name ASC
```

Você está ordenando primeiro pelo `qty_pass`, assim, caso não tiver valores iguais no `qty_pass`, então nunca irá ordenar o `material_name`.

Exemplo:

```
quantidade | item
    400    | carro
    340    | disco
    240    | dado
    180    | carro
    120    | disco
     89    | faca
     59    | faca
```

**Invertendo as ordens:**

```
ORDER BY material_name ASC, qty_pass DESC
```

Desta forma, irá ordenar primeiro pelo `material_name` e depois pelo `qty_pass`.

Exemplo:

```
item   | quantidade
carro  |    400
carro  |    180
dado   |    240
disco  |    340
disco  |    120
faca   |     89
faca   |     59
```

---

No `ORDER BY`, a ordem dos fatores altera o resultado.

```
ORDER BY condicao1, condicao2 DESC, condicao3 ASC, ...
```

***Quando se tem valores iguais na primeira condição (já ordenada), ele irá ordenar a segunda, e assim em diante, na sequencia determinada.***

*Quando não é determinado `ASC` ou `DESC`, por padrão, irá ordenar `ASC`*